# Auto Send Emails for every new row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I want to receive email notification when new rows are added to Google Sheet. I am using this sheet to receive form submissions from HTML form.
The code I am using the code given below, with time trigger and a sent tag to identify already sent notifications. The issue is that whenever the trigger is initiated, it only sends the last row, even if it is already been sent. I also tried using onChange trigger but it does not work when form is submitted. Only works when a change is made manually to the form

```
function SendEmail() {
 var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var StartRow = 2;
 var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
 var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,5);
 var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();

 var message = "";
 for (i in AllValues) {
 var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];

 var EmailSent = CurrentRow[5];
 var Sender = CurrentRow[1];

 if (EmailSent == "Sent") 
     continue;

  message =
    "<p>A new response was recorded:</p>" +
      "<p><b>Name: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Email: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Message: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>"


  var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;


  ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 5).setValue("sent");
}


 var SendTo = "email@gmail.com";

 var Subject = "New Form Submission";

  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: SendTo,
      subject: Subject,
      htmlBody: message,
});
}
```

Kindly help me resolve the issue or suggest another code that would do the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a time-driven trigger use a on change trigger with a condition for the change type equal to `INSERT_ROW`.

Simple example:

```js
function respondToOnChange(e){
  if(e.changeType === 'INSERT_ROW'){
    // do something
  } else {
    // do nothing
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding a OnChange trigger to the script but the script doesn't work then.. OnChange is only detected when you manually edit the document. This document receives responses from an html form and OnChange trigger is useless here.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify it. I suggest you to add a [mcve] including the how the form is editin your spreadsheet.